# GStreamer pipeline generated by Flumotion stalls

Tags: video-encoding, gstreamer, transcoding

The following gstreamer pipeline was generated by Flumotion while transcoding a file but it stalls

I am not sure entirely why as I only started developing gstreamer application recently. I am guessing that it is because of lack of memory. The file is large (1+ Gb) and I am running this on server with only 2Gb.

Please help.

```
gst-launch -v filesrc location=vid1.mkv ! decodebin2 name=decoder ! queue ! audiorate ! audioconvert ! legacyresample ! 'audio/x-raw-int, rate=44100, channels=2;audio/x-raw-float, rate=44100, channels=2' ! lame ! mp3parse ! queue ! muxer. decoder. ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videorate ! videoscale method=1 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=180, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, framerate=25/1;video/x-raw-rgb, width=320, height=180, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, framerate=25/1' ! videobox left=0 top=-30 right=0 bottom=-30 ! ffenc_flv bitrate=500000 ! queue ! flvmux name=muxer ! filesink location=vid1.flv
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you get any errors? Try running `export GST_DEBUG="GST_ELEMENT_*:5";` first, it will provide more debug output.

Comment: would be worth to get the backtrace when it hangs, install all debuging packages, attach stalling process with gdb --pid `pidof gst-launch`, then run "thread apply all bt".

Comment: I added the Failed Report that flumotion generates since thats nice to look at. I will try the debug flags. I am guessing that flumotion doesn't actually use gst_launch to run the pipeline so i can't really attach to a gst_launch process, i should be able to attach to flumotion.

Comment: Please either convert that edit into an answer and post it below, or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determinined that it was not a gstreamer problem. FLumotion seems to be killing the process when it takes too long.